# How to parse nsdictionary data using nsserlization.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, nsdictionary

I have dictionary data like this and one array on image.

> {  "result":"Successful","data":{"id":"12","product_name":"12\" Round
>   Plate","sku":"ECOW12RP","description":"Diameter 12 inch x\tDepth 0.9
>   inch","price":"153.00","business_price":"365.00","image":[{"image":"1454499068ecow12rp_01.jpg"}],"pack_size":"20","business_pack_size":"50","category":"2,3","tax_class":"1","created":"2016-02-03","altered":"2016-02-03
>   17:52:58","status":"1","deleted":"0","arrange":"1","delivery":"150.00"}}

I want to parse all the key values from it. this is the code which i use for this task.

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"d %ld", (long)id);
    NSString* myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", id];
    NSURL *producturl = [NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://dev1.brainpulse.org/ecoware1/webservices/product/"   ];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myNewString  relativeToURL:producturl];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage * productimage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSURL *absURL = [url absoluteURL];
    NSLog(@"absURL = %@", absURL);

    NSURLRequest *request= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:absURL];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection   didReceiveResponse:(nonnull NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Did receive response");
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection  didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    [data appendData:thedata];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

    NSLog(@"arr %@", dictionary);
    [productdetail removeAllObjects];

    for (NSString *tmp in dictionary)

        NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [temp setObject:@"product_name" forKey:@"product_name"];

    //[temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
    // [temp setObject:[tmp objectForKey:@"image"] forKey:@"image"];

    [productdetail addObject:temp];

    NSLog(@"detail %@", productdetail);
}
```

I tried to parse string from `nsdictionary` with the help of for loop, but I get product details array null, i don't know why it not get key value.

> i am parse data which is in nsdictionary but i have null array when i try to parse image array in this json data please look at this json data.

```
{"result":"Successful","data":{"id":"2","product_name":"6\" Round Plate","sku":"ECOW6RP","description":"Diameter 6.0 (inch) x Depth 0.6 (inch)\r\n\r\nPerfect for finger foods!","price":"42.89","business_price":"100.00","image":[{"image":"1454499251ecow6rp_01.jpg"}],"pack_size":"20","business_pack_size":"50","category":"2,3","tax_class":"1","created":"2016-01-19","altered":"2016-02-06 16:06:10","status":"1","deleted":"0","arrange":"1","delivery":"150.00"}}
```

Comment: There are many areas this could fail at.  Only you can tell us where by debugging it.

Comment: you getting values here -NSLog(@"arr %@", dictionary); ?

Comment: ok @trojanfoe  my code is not crash now, but when i tried to add temp in my array and then i print array(productdetail), it gives me null value

Comment: can someone help me plz?

Comment: Add break point before adding temp in your productdetail array. Make sure by looking at debug area your productdetail array must not be nil.

Comment: i already add a break point plz look at my debug area output:- 2016-02-04 15:22:06.961 Ecoware[1224:79840] detail (null)
2016-02-04 15:22:06.961 Ecoware[1224:79840] detail (null)
2016-02-04 15:22:06.961 Ecoware[1224:79840] detail (null)
2016-02-04 15:22:06.961 Ecoware[1224:79840] detail (null)
2016-02-04 15:22:06.961 Ecoware[1224:79840] detail (null)

Comment: Is `productdetail` initialized at all? `tmp` (better `key`) represents each key in the dictionary enumeration. if you want the value for the specific key, write `[dictionary objectForKey:tmp]` or shorter `dictionary[tmp]`

Comment: yes sir it is initialised already

Comment: The debug log says it's not initialized otherwise it must not be `nil`

Comment: ok sir now i get this error 2016-02-04 16:12:54.385 Ecoware[1303:90867] detail (
        {
    },
        {
    },
        {
    },
        {
    },

Comment: can anyone tell me that how will i get the product_name from this data?

Comment: You see my point, yeah?  Your question is not focused on the exact issue.  You will not find an answer until you improve it.

Comment: in which line you are struck...

Comment: i am getting error in this block for (NSDictionary *tmp in dictionary)
    {
        
        NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
      //  [temp setObject:[tmp @"product_name" forKey:@"product_name"]];
      
        
        [tmp objectForKey:@"product_name"];
        NSLog(@"dict %@", tmp);
        
        
        [productdetail addObject:temp];
        
        NSLog(@"detail %@", productdetail);
        
    }
 and i have an error like this plz see ;- [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7977c5b0'

Comment: `tmp` is 'String', [tmp objectForKey`… will fail always. See my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**Option-1**

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

[productdetail removeAllObjects];

if (dictionary)
{

NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[temp setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"product_name"];
 [productdetail addObject:temp];
 }
```

Comment: show once what the result u get in here **dictionary**

Comment: awesome Anbu.Karthik sir, what i can say about you. you are always rocking sir

Comment: this is the output i get and that's what i want 2016-02-04 16:33:31.934 Ecoware[1356:96515] product detail (
        {
        "product_name" = "12\" Round Plate";
    }
)

Comment: i need to revise my son basics now

Comment: That code needs more error checking.  If `product_name` does not exist in the input data it will crash.

Comment: ok sir so should i get value from dictionary in string form??

Comment: @trojanfoe -- how do u say that it will come on errror , the reason I check the dictionary or not after that I include the value..., this is related to questioner , questioner need to check every key is empty or not

Comment: No it relates to you and you wrote the code.  I've already mentioned what will trigger the crash.

Comment: @sandeeptomar -- always get the same JSON part of all webservices , it is easy to access all Serliziation...

Comment: hello sir i edit my question for a little bit issue can you please help me.?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific question to get the `product_name` data into your dictionary, this will work

```
   NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

   NSMutableDictionary *temp = [NSMutableDictionary new];

if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"product_name"]){
   [temp setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"product_name"] forKey:@"product_name"];
}
```

If you print out the dictionary you made, you should see it is in there.

```
NSLog(@"the temp dictionary value for ProductName: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"product_name"];
```

Comment: this line get me null value(NSLog(@"the temp dictionary value for ProductName: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"product_name"];)

Comment: like this the temp dictionary value for ProductName: (null)